# Setting and connecting pixels

Tags: mfc, gdi

I want to set pixels where the mouse click is made and connect those pixels. My code is as follows.

```
  void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags,CPoint point)
  { 
  CDC* pDC= GetDC();
  int x[100],y[100];
  POINT Pt[4];

  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    SetPixel(NULL,Pt[i].x,Pt[i].y,RGB(0,0,0));
    pDC->MoveTo(Pt[i].x,Pt[i].y);
    pDC->LineTo(Pt[i+1].x,Pt[i+1].y);
 }
 }
```

But I am not getting anything in the output other than a blank screen. Pls help.

Comment: You shouldn't normally paint to the screen anywhere other than in OnDraw() or OnPaint().  Have a look at the "Scribble" sample.

Comment: you are not using the current Mouse point because you are not using the "CPoint point" variable, you should store the last point and trace the line from there

Comment: But I want to set the pixel when I click the mouse button. Shouldn't I use the SetPixel function in LButtonDown()?

Comment: Pt[i].x will always be 0 because you didn't initialize it

Comment: also Pt[i+1] will give you an exception when "i" reaches the value "3", because 3+1=4 and Pt[4] means the 5th position of the vector, and you only have 4 positions

Comment: the parameter "CPoint point" holds the position of the mouse

Comment: How to initialize Pt[i].x to the position where the mouse is clicked? and I need only 4 points. Thats why I have used i<4.

Comment: the vector "POINT Pt" will be destroyed every time the mouse is clicked, so with your current code you will never fill the vector".
so you have to declare that variable as a member of your class "CChildView" and use it inside the OnLButtonDown method

Comment: I have declared the 'POINT Pt' in CChildView header file but still not getting anything

Comment: have you assigned any value to that "Point Pt" variable now?

Comment: I want the value to be the location where the mouse is clicked.

Comment: again, you can get the value from the parameter "CPoint point". Inside the OnLButtonDown method use point.x to get the X position and point.y to get the y position =)

Comment: for(int i=0;i<4;i++) { pDC->SetPixel(point.x,point.y,RGB(0,0,0)); } I have used this code to set the pixel where the mouse is clicked. But if i click for 10 times I am ending up with 10 points. I want only 4 points. If I click for the 5th time nothing should happen. Is that for loop condition correct to do that?

Comment: to do that you will have to create another member variable in your "CChildView" class to store the current amount of points you have, so every time you get into the method you will have to increment it. and then to check when you reach the amount you want you will have to use an "if"

Comment: PS: you don't need the "for"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### create the variables you need

in the CChildView class add a variable that stores the last point, and a variable that stores the amount of points you currently have

```
CPoint m_lastPoint;
int m_iPointAmount;
```

#### in the CChildView constructor initialize the variables

```
m_lastPoint.x = -1;
m_lastPoint.y = -1;
m_iPointAmount = 1;
```

#### in the OnLButtonDown method

1. check if it is the first point, and update the member variable
2. if it is not the first point and you have less than 4 points, connect the new point with the last one

`if (m_lastPoint.x != -1 && m_iPointAmount <5)`

`{`

`CDC* pDC= GetDC();`

`pDC->MoveTo(m_lastPoint.x,m_lastPoint.y);`

`pDC->LineTo(point.x,point.y);`

`}`

`m_lastPoint = point;`

`m_iPointAmount++`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did exactly as you said. I am able to connect the pixels. Suppose if I draw a square , it has 4 points. I should be able to drag those 4 points with mouse click and place it in a new position. What are the steps to achieve that. Pls advice or should I start a new thread?

Comment: i think that you should start a new thread, because that involves other concepts. If my answer and my comments solved your problem, then please select it as your answer =). anyway, you might be interested in some graphics engine like OpenGL (https://www.opengl.org).